# Is there a way to pip install all requirements.txt in subfolders

Tags: python, deployment, pip, setuptools

Suppose I have a folder called `plugins` with `n` number of plugins in it. Each plugin has it's own requirements.txt file and there's a base requirements.txt file on the top level.

```
  +requirements.txt
  |
  +Plugins+
          +-----+  Plugin1/
          |
          +-----+  plugin2/
          |
          +-----+  Plugin3/
          |
          +-----+  Plugin4/+
          |                |
          +-----+          +---+  requirements.txt
          |
          +-----+
          |
          +-----+
```

Is there a simple way, in which I can install all the requirements.txt in all the modules as part of deployment.

I tried specifying `-r plugins/*/requirements.txt` and it didn't work; Is there a elegant way of handling this ?

Comment: you could use `find` and do something like this: `find . -name 'requirements.txt' -exec pip install -r {} \;`

Comment: @StegSchreck - What language is that?

Comment: `find` is a bash command